# Google map API v2 Android - Markers & scale

Tags: android, google-maps, scale, markers

I m actually developping a simple application using Google MAP API on Android, and I m facing some problems :

In fact, I have many markers to put on the map (~4000) and they slow down considerably the application.

Moreover, according to the scale, the markers only reduce there sizes and not group themselves.
Example :

I have to put 400 markers on Paris. If I reduce or improve the scale, I always have 400 markers. I need to have 1 marker with a number when the scale has a certain value.

Do you know a simple way to make it easily (using a tool in the api) instead of coding it by myself ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement Google Map Marker Clustering in your app, follow this link : 
[Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering)